# Highcharts renders blank svg in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

**Why is highcharts rendering a (nearly) empty svg?** It creates a properly sized div with attributes and the svg tag with a nested desc tag as shown below, but no chart.

#### The Output

```
...
<div id="commissions-chart" data-highcharts-chart="0">
  <div class="highcharts-container skies" id="highcharts-0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 1627px; height: 400px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1627" height="400">   
      <desc>Created with Highstock 1.3.1</desc>
      <defs></defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
...
<script src="/assets/jquery172.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.192.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/z_highstock/1 first/highstock.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/z_highstock/2 second/highcharts-more.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/zz_my_charts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
...
```

#### The Chart Script (Highcharts Sample Script)

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#commissions-chart').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

#### Console Errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined jquery172.min.js:5
```

Comment: Why is your `<script src=...` after your html?  My guess is you are executing javascript on elements not yet loaded into the DOM.

Comment: No javascript is executed before the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the issue is a incompatibility with another charting plugin: Flot. After removing the Flot files from my asset pipeline the chart showed up.

Comment: It's not just another chart plugin, but may as well be a jQuery plugin, in my case it was a jquery.resize.js plugin

Answer (score 0):

There's also a incompatibility issue with the plugin jquery.ba-resize (would have added this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation)